# How does telnet differ from a raw tcp connection

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming, telnet

I am trying to send commands to a server via a python script. I can see the socket connection being established on the server. But the commands I am sending across , do not seem to make it through(server does a read on the socket).
The server currently supports a telnet command interpreter. ie: you telnet to the command address and port, and you can start sending 
string commands. 
My question is , is there anything fundamentally different from sending strings over a tcp socket, as opposed to using telnet.
I have used both raw sockets as well as the Twisted framework.

Comment: The difference is the same as the difference between a car and an engine. Telnet **may** be implemented using TCP sockets, just like a car may be built using a specific type of engine.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Telnet is a way of passing control information about the communication channel.  It defines line-buffering, character echo, etc, and is done through a series of will/wont/do/dont messages when the connection starts (and, on rare occasions, during the session).

That's probably not what your server documentation means.  Instead, it probably means that you can open a TCP socket to the port using a program like "Telnet" and interact with a command interpreter on the server.

When the Telnet program connects, it typically listens for these control messages before responding in kind and so will work with TCP/socket connections that don't actually use the telnet protocol, reverting to a simple raw pipe.  The server must do all character echo, line buffering, etc.

So in *your* case, the server is likely using a raw TCP stream with no telnet escape sequences and thus there is no difference.

Comment: python is brilliant that way. there is a telnetlib.

Comment: @Brian_White, could you provide a doc reference for "reverting to a simple raw pipe"?

Comment: I'm not sure that it is part of any RFC. The statement comes from my experience writing a `telnet` client and comparing it to the behavior of existing clients, hence the "typical" qualifier.  Of course, it won't be completely raw because the `IAC` character can't be passed directly but that generally isn't a problem for a console user interface.  You can check it yourself by using `telnet` to connect to any open port (e.g. web port 80) and observe that no `IAC` control sequences are sent by the client.

Comment: I didn't understand the third sentence. If I trace the connection, it seems raw.

Comment: Assuming you mean the third _paragraph_: The only difference would be some control sequences embedded in the stream.  `IAC FOO BAR` (in binary, not ascii)  If the server never sends them (and many systems do not) then you will have something very similar to a raw connection.  I say "similar" because it isn't fully 8-bit clean; any `IAC` (0xFF) characters should be escaped as `IAC IAC`.

Answer (score 13):

Keep in mind that Telnet is an **application layer** protocol while TCP is a **transport layer** protocol. Telnet *uses* TCP in order to transmit data. That is a big fundamental difference between Telnet and TCP.

**See:** [OSI Model wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model)

Answer (score 4):

From the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet) on telnet

> ...User data is interspersed in-band with Telnet control information...

So, to answer your question, yes, telnet does differ from a raw socket.

[RFC 854](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc854) describes the telnet protocol if you want to try implementing it or you could use [telnetlib](http://docs.python.org/library/telnetlib.html) if you'd prefer an existing python client.